# Javascript & html: opacity change causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I set out to make a simple fade transition between 3 elements which are on top of each other by using absolute positioning and changing their opacity via Javascript, but the following code does not work as I had expected, and I am unsure as to why.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#item0, #item1, #item2 {
    opacity: 0.0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 26px;
}
#item0 { opacity: 1.0; }
</style>
<script>
var count = 0;
var items;
function init(){
    items = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("div");
    setInterval(fade, 5000);
}
function fade(){
    fadeElements(items[count], items[(count + 1) % 3]);
    count = (count + 1) % 3;
}
function fadeElements(prevItem, nextItem){
    prevItem.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    nextItem.style.opacity += 0.1;
    if(nextItem.style.opacity < 1.0){
        setTimeout(function(){fadeElements(prevItem, nextItem)}, 50);
    } else {
        nextItem.style.opacity = 1.0;
        prevItem.style.opacity = 0.0;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="container">
    <div id="item0"> 0 </div>
    <div id="item1"> 1 </div>
    <div id="item2"> 2 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it is something to do with using += with element.style.opacity, but Firefox gives me unhelpful errors and Chrome gives no errors at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.style.opacity` is being retrieved as a string. To fix this, replace these lines:

```
prevItem.style.opacity -= 0.1;
nextItem.style.opacity += 0.1;
```

With these:

```
prevItem.style.opacity = (+prevItem.style.opacity) - 0.1;
nextItem.style.opacity = (+nextItem.style.opacity) + 0.1;
```

Additionally, for the first iteration, the zero will flash momentarily. This is because although it was set to `1.0` in the CSS, it has no `style` attribute in the HTML. You can fix this by setting its opacity to `1.0` in `init` (right after the `items =` line):

```
items[0].style.opacity = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Memebers of element.style object are strings. So try this

```
prevItem.style.opacity = parseFloat(prevItem.style.opacity) - 0.1;
nextItem.style.opacity = parseFloat(nextItem.style.opacity) + 0.1;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right about the objects being strings, however parseFloat doesn't work fully for me. The first box fades out, but the second never shows up.

Comment: Edit: This also works fine if I initialize all 3 item's opacity before accessing them, otherwise parseFloat chokes.

Comment: As usual: `parseFloat(prevItem.style.opacity || "0")`